# Jenkins API intermittent authentication errors

Tags: ansible, jenkins

I'm using Ansible's `jenkins_job` task to set up some Jenkins jobs. I'm authenticating with a username+password which is authenticated as a Linux user on the Jenkins machine.

```
  - name: Install my job
    jenkins_job:
      name: "my-job"
      user: "{{ jenkins_admin_user }}"
      password: "{{ jenkins_admin_pass}}"
      config: "{{ lookup('template', 'templates/jobs/my-job.xml') }}"
```

When I run Ansible some jobs get installed but part-way through the run, after installing some of my jobs (a different number each time), I get this error:

> Unable to validate if job exists, Error in request. Possibly authentication failed [401]: Invalid password/token for user: my-jenkins-user

It's clear that my credentials work - jobs show up in Jenkins. So why am I getting this error?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ansible, but here're some questions. Is the interval between installing things and the error showing up generally predictable (e.g. always about 2 minutes after the first successful auth)? Is it that the credentials remain valid for a time period but then "expire" after some time and the user must re-authenticate?

Comment: Do you also use Ansible to set up user authentication/authorization?  If so, Ansible may be locking itself out from Jenkins partway through the run.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the Jenkins API, not with Ansible. The solution is to [use an API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients) key instead of a password.

Log into Jenkins and click your username in the top right, then click "Configure" to see your API token. To use the key, just enter it instead of a password when authenticating with the Jenkins API.